# exterior powers of representations which are irreducible/not irreducible

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

For the symmetric group $S_n$, let $V$ denotes the $n-1$ dimensional standard representation.

Then an exercise in Fulton-Harris says that for $k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$, the $k$-th exterior powers of $V$ are still irreducible representations of $S_n$.

My question is related, and it is not about this specific group. Instead, I was looking for an example of a group $G$ different from $S_n$.

**Q.** Is there example of a finite group $G$, different from $S_n$, with an irreducible representation $V$ of dimension $>1$, such that

(1) For some $k\geq 2$, the $k$-th exterior power of $V$ is irreducible.

(2) For some $r\geq 2$, the $r$-th exterior power of $V$ is not irreducible.

Further, I will appreciate if I could find the required example of group of small orders, and also the powers are easy to compute by hand (instead of verifying it by computer programs such as GAP).

Comment: The top non-zero exterior power is $1$-dimensional and hence irreducible, so the first condition will always hold.

Comment: An example with $k=2$ and $r=3$ is the $6$-dimensional irreducible module for $A_7$. I checked it by computer, but I expect it could be checked by hand using characters.

Comment: @Derek: This type of examples I was looking for; still, I will try some of small order even. But, since I have not known in general any kind of results about exterior powers and their reducibility/irreducibility, so I was going first through examples.

Comment: You can get some examples having property (2) by just knowing the dimensions of irreducibles. For example, the irreps of $A_5$ have dimension 1, 3, 4, or 5, and so it's immediate that the second exterior power of a 4 or 5 dimension irrep must be reducible, just by dimension counting.

Comment: Take any finite group $G$ with an irreducible representation of dimension at least $4$ and let $V$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ of maximal dimension. By our assumptions on the dimension of $V$ the representation $\bigwedge^k V$  is reducible for $1<k<\dim V$.